# how to random a list using python

Tags: python, list

this is my code :

```
import random

a = [12,2,3,4,5,33,14,124,55,233,565]
b=[]
for i in a:
    b.append(random.choice(a))

print a,b
```

but i think maybe has a method like **sort** named **randomList**

has this method in python .

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import random

a = [12,2,3,4,5,33,14,124,55,233,565]

b = a[:]
random.shuffle(b)

# b: [55, 12, 33, 5, 565, 3, 233, 2, 124, 4, 14]
```

This will not modify `a`.

To modify `a` inplace, just do `random.shuffle(a)`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [`random.shuffle`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle).

Answer (score 2):

you could use `random.shuffle`

```
random.shuffle(a)
```

would give a random order of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> random.sample(a, len(a))

[14, 124, 565, 233, 55, 12, 5, 33, 4, 3, 2]
```

this has several advantages over `random.shuffle`:

- a new list is returned (no changes to original a)
- the resulting list is in selection order so that all sub-slices will also be valid random samples
- in random.shuffle, [most permutations of a long sequence can never be generated](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle).

All elements of `a` are part of the returned list. See more [here](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample).